# Binomial coefficient proof (combinatorics)

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I need to prove the following Binomial coefficients

$(1) \{(a,b,c)|a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}, 1 \le a\lt b\lt c\le n$}=$\binom{n}{3}$

$(2) \{(a,b,c)|a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}, 1 \le a\le b\le c\le n$}=$\binom{n+2}{3}$

I know that:
$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

My idea for (1) would be:

=$\frac {n·(n - 1)·(n - 2)} { 3!} $ = $\frac {n·(n - 1)·(n - 2)·(n - 3)!} { (3!·(n - 3)!)} $= $\frac {n!} { (3!·(n - 3)!)} $ = $\binom{n}{3}$

However, I have no idea ow to do (2)

I would really appreciate it, if someone could help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could break this up into cases where you have all three distinct integers like in the first case in ${n}\choose {3}$ ways; then the case where $a=b<c$ in ${n}\choose {2}$ ways,  the case where $a<b=c$ in ${n}\choose {2}$ ways, and finally the case where $a=b=c$ in ${n}\choose {1}$ ways. So you have the sum ${n}\choose {1}$ $+2$${n}\choose{2}$ $+$ ${n}\choose{3}$, which is the same thing as ${n+1}\choose{2}$ $+$ ${n+1}\choose {3}$=${n+2}\choose{3}$.

Also, you could easily think of $a=1+\alpha$, $b=a+\beta$, $c=b+\gamma$, and $1+\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta=n$, where each $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta\geq 0$. Thus we need integers solutions to $\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta=n-1$ which is ${(n-1)+(4-1)}\choose{4-1}$$=$${n+2}\choose{3}$.